# Gender-neutral equivalent of "Man of the world"

Tags: single-word-requests

> *You and I are men of the world. Where does this leave the fair sex?*

I'm looking for a noun or noun-phrase that captures the essence of *"Man of the world"*, but which can be equally applied to men and women.

I suppose I'm looking for a noun for a person who has enough savoir-vivre to be equally comfortable as a baseball game, an operatic performance, a beau monde cocktail party, and a strip club. A little help, please?

***Alternatively***, I could accept a gender-specific equivalent that applies to women.

"She's been around the block" has all kinds of ... uh ... irrelevant ... connotations. As does "woman of the world."

The kind of woman I have in mind knows her Verdi and Giordano; favors Hals over Rembrandt and has a weakness for John Singer Sargent; can fix her own plumbing if need be; can appreciate an expensive bottle of champagne *and* can drink, sing loudly off-key, and dance with the best of them at a truck stop. She's hardly a stranger to an evening gown but doesn't mind wearing mountain boots. She has read, and can casually quote from, Marcus Aurelius, but she can hold her own in a conversation about last season's Stanley Cup champions. She's hardly a bleeding heart, but isn't sanctimonious either: when a hobo sitting on the sidewalk pushes his plastic cup towards her, she won't pretend that he doesn't exist; nor will she lecture him on the benefits of getting and keeping a job: she'll deposit a five-dollar bill in his cup and continue on her way. Above all, she's not easily embarrassed. Yes, she will step into the alley to pee when she can't hold it anymore and has no other options, and she WON'T make a big deal of it.

A word or a phrase, *please*.

Comment: So you want a gender-neutral term for "man of the world"?  Maybe "worldly wise"?  (Though that term is not a dead-on match for "man of the world".)

Comment: It is unclear what you are looking for. A word that covers both men and women? Or a noun for 'worldly' that also is non-gendered?

Comment: Without a little more clarity you will start picking up close votes.

Comment: People of the world?

Comment: "We've all ***been around the block*** a few times.

Comment: It's not very clear, but I take it that you want to substitute the noun "men" with something that is gender neutral, which in that case could be: *compatriots; citizens, adults, comrades, people, men and women,...* etc. But the idiom is ....*"we/you and I are men of the world"*... meaning "experienced", "worldly",  if you change the noun, the idiom becomes less recognizable, and the speaker, especially if male, risks sounding like someone who has an issue with feminists or with political correctness. Not cool.

Comment: Reading your expanded description, I suspect you simply want some term to describe this fictitious idealized woman you're imagining.

Comment: @HotLicks: What if I did? ... Fictitious, maybe. Idealized? Hmm. Social mobility may be a myth, but a man can dream, right? Don't be such a killjoy.  We're going to put Trump in the White House soon. Can you imagine the entertainment value?

Comment: Has no one mentioned the Cole Porter song [The lady is a Tramp](http://www.metrolyrics.com/the-lady-is-a-tramp-lyrics-frank-sinatra.html)?

Comment: *Belle de Jour* describes a sophisticated woman who is comfortable in a brothel.

Comment: @Jimmy: I saw the movie a while ago, so don't hold me to it, but isn't she not quite right in the head?

Comment: I was surprised how old this phrase is... never would have expected Middle Ages. And apparently "woman of the world" is what we use for women. I thought you might be able to make up your own word, though -- something related to *sophisticated*, but I'm not sure that carries the same sentiments.

Comment: I found the initial wording of this this question ridiculously confusing, I'm proposing an edit which, after several minutes of head-scratching, I *think* captures what you're getting at...

Comment: @user568458: You must be as beautiful as you are brilliant.

Comment: Err... That's a bit creepy. Don't say that to this elusive woman when you first meet her

Comment: @user568458: Perspicacious, too! Wow.

Comment: Aren't you combining *down-to-earth* with *renaissance man*?  I'm not sure you have a phrase for either gender that clearly suggests both of those combined.

Comment: Citizen of the world?

Answer (score 3):

It is not a perfect match, but *[cosmopolitan](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cosmopolitan)*, in the sense of definitions #1 and #5 (depending on whether adjective or noun) in the link, is close to fitting your meaning:

> *adj*: free from local, provincial, or national ideas, prejudices, or attachments; at home all over the world.
>
> *noun*: a person who is free from local, provincial, or national bias or attachment; citizen of the world; cosmopolite.

For an example:

> Alice has traveled in and studied many cultures, her *cosmopolitan* nature has let her be comfortable conversing with all kinds of people.

Answer (score 2):

> **Polymath**
>
> *noun*:
> a person of wide-ranging knowledge or learning.

I'm a big fan of the word, and it's gender-neutral to boot.